# How to access from Java Client to SOAP Server using Custom Binding properties

Tags: java, web-services, wcf, soap, google-api-java-client

I try to write java client to access a SOAP Server which is already used for another clients.

SOAP Server built with .Net envirement which I didn't know that part. I have given the wsdl and some files that include custom binding properties files.
I import wsdl to make Java code via Idea so I have binding class which in wsdl. I finished the implementation for these classes come from wsdl. However I cannot get any response when I call service.

Custom binding properties file has these tag

```
   <customBinding> <binding name="MyBinding"> <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" /> 
<textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressingAugust2004" /> </binding> </customBinding>
```

Here is my question how can I apply these custom binding to my java client?

Comment: Can you provide some error information from the log, so that the problem can be quickly located.